# bitbucket wrong ssh passcode

Tags: git, macos, ssh, bitbucket

Hello im kinda new in the bitbucket, my office use bitbucket as version control and using ssh to authenticate.

the thing is i was able to create ssh key, login and cloned the repo. the next day im using sourcetree to push my commit but i entered wrong passcode.

but when i tried to push again the terminal doesnt prompt me to re-enter the passcode. but shown the

```
fatal: 'my_branch' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

so i went to bitbucket and delete my existing key create new one but it still give same error.

is there any way to solve this error, or delete somekind of ssh history on my mac

*im using macos 10.15.7

Comment: "fatal: 'my_branch' does not appear to be a git repository"—do you have a _directory_ called `my_branch`? Normally Git doesn't create directories for branches. Are you using multiple worktrees?

Answer (score 0):

First, check if your [remote repository settings on SourceTree](https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/viewing-remote-hosted-repositories-780870170.html)

If the URL starts with `https://`, it would not use SSH at all.

[image: URL]

I mention that because "not asking for your password again" is a behavior associated with HTTPS URLs whose credentials can be cached by a `git config credential.helper`.

If it is SSH though, try and restart SourceTree, in order to force the SSH agent to be reinitialized: that will trigger a prompt for the passphrase of your private key (it is not a password) to be queried again.